# How to disable copy paste on pdf.js when it is embedded on Thinkific

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdf.js.express

I hope you are well,

Does someone know how to disable the copy paste feature on the pdf.js pdf viewer when it is embedded on the Thinkific https://thinkific.com/ platform ?

I disabled the copy and paste option on a pdf thanks to Adobe Acrobat Pro's protection feature
I uploaded it on the Thinkific platform using their embedded pdf viewer pdf.js
While the protection works when I open the pdf with Adobe Acrobat Pro (I am not able to copy paste anymore), the protection does not work on the Thinkific embededded pdf viewer pdf.js (I am still able to copy paste content from the pdf).

How can I sort this out ?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot prevent it. It just makes things annoying for the end user if you try. If I would encounter such a PDF I'd simply use devtools to extract the text or disable the "protection". Also, one can simply use ChatGPT to read the text as well. So I don't see any use in this.

Comment: Hi KJ, thank you for your reply! I did encrypt my pdf with Adobe Acrobat Pro and the protection does work when I open it with Adobe Acrobat Pro, Google, etc. but when I open it in Thinkific (which uses the pdf.js pdf viewer) I am still able to copy paste (the protection does not work). How can I disable the copy paste option on pdf.js given that it is embedded in Thinkific ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.